# Convert output tangent angles (Degree) from (−π2,π2) range to (0, 2π) range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, trigonometry

I am working on the task, where I have to project each node (x, y coordinates) of a geometry places at (0,0) to the outer circumference which is also placed at (0,0) with radius 4.

Question: I have computed an angle theta (in degree) using below code and got an output like below.

```
angle = []
for i in range(len(x_new)-1):
    angle.append(math.degrees(math.atan(y_new[i] / x_new[i])))
    
angle
```

Output:

```
[72.40757543781841,
 62.52556837372287,
 34.69515353123397,
 -28.300755766006375,
 -13.570434385161485,
 -38.418055344821994,
 -60.52411099675425,
 82.5685920288275,
 50.440332031005504,
 33.31063082456081,
 11.309932474020215,
 20.224859431168078,
 66.80140948635182,
 -71.56505117707799,
 -83.15722658736907]
```

I know that `tangent` function has a range (−π2,π2), but I want these angles in output in the range of 0 to 360.

Question: How can I convert these angels in the range of 0 to 360?

Comment: Please add enough information to make the snippet runnable

Comment: Please don't spam tags without reading their guidance, and always do your research before posting a question. Most of the problems we have are not new :)

Comment: I apologize to you for posting this question. However, the another question (that is already answerd) is for me is confusing. And I could not find a way how this method  will help me in my task. But, yes, I will see that answer again and will try to understand it. Thank you and kindly accept my apology.

Comment: No need to apologize. Just replace pi with 180, 2pi with 360, etc. in the other answer. If you're working with numbers, I suggest you move to numpy instead of math anyway. You can rewrite the numpy operations as a loop if it makes things easier for you, but the selection process is all there.